# How to report results from the likelihood ratio test of two lme models?

Tags: mixed-model, likelihood-ratio, reporting

I am trying to find an appropriate way to report the results of the likelihood ratio test in a paper. I wrote:

The likelihood ratio tests reported a significant main effect of FE (χ²(1)=6.06, p < 0.0001) on DV.

The reviewer, however, asks me to report the estimate of FE. Would it be correct? The FE was present only in one of the models that were compared to each other. I though that beta coefficients were not relevant at this level of analysis any more, is this accurate ? How would you argue this case?